# Rmarkdown: how to add more space before tittle?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm using [vitae](https://github.com/ropenscilabs/vitae) package to make my CV. However, my name is very close to the top.

How should I add more spacing between the top and my name.

I've found that I can use this in pure Latex to increase the top spacing:

```
\usepackage[scale=0.75,top=1cm]{geometry}
```

But getting this error:

```
tlmgr search --file --global "/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex"
C:\texlive\2018\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl: TLPDB::from_file could not download http://ftp.inf.utfsm.cl/pub/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb;
C:\texlive\2018\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl: maybe the repository setting should be changed.
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

Error: Failed to compile omar_gonzales_diaz_mktg.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See omar_gonzales_diaz_mktg.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

[image]

**Rmarkdown code:**

This is the Rmarkdown code I use to generate the PDF.

````
---
name: Manuel A Gomez Ruiz
position: "Marketing Digital - Ecommerce"
address: "Universidad de Pennsilvania"
phone: 96-330-5265
www: omardiaz.rd.io
email: "oms@gmail.com"
twitter: o_gles
github: OmonD
linkedin: orgles
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %Y')`"
aboutme: "Postgrado en Marketing Digital por la Universidad de Pennsilvania"
headcolor: 224190
geometry: "top=4cm,bottom=1cm"
output: vitae::awesomecv
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
library(vitae)
library(tibble)
library(tidyverse)
library(RefManageR)
```

# Sobre mi

 * Estudié Marketing Digital, con conocimientos de programación.
 * Programo en los lenguajes: R y Python.
 * Deporte favorito: Paleta Frontón.
 * Idiomas: Inglés, Alemán.
 * Me gusta viajar y conocer gente nueva.


# Educación
```{r}
tribble(
  ~ degree, ~ uni, ~ loc, ~ dates, ~ details,

    "Marketing, Especialización Online", "Universidad de Pennsylvania", "coursera.org", "2014", "Marketing Strategy and Brand Positioning. Customer Decision Making and the Role of Brand.",
  "Diplomado en Marketing Digital", "Universidad de Piura", "Piura, Perú", "Mar. 2013 - Jul. 2013", "Mejor trabajo final, Plan de Marketing Digital 2013.",
  "Egresado de la Facultad de Comunicación", "Universidad de Piura", "Piura, Perú", "Mar. 2007 - Dic. 2011", "Tercio Superior, Especialización en Marketing."
) %>% 
  detailed_entries(degree, dates, uni, loc, details)
```

# Experiencia
```{r}
tribble(
  ~ role, ~ company, ~ loc, ~ dates, ~ details,
  "Jefe de Tecnología", "My Company", "Lima, Perú", "Ago. 2018 - Presente", "Cofundador, encargado del desarrollo de la webapp y puesta en producción. Responsable del correcto funcionamiento del sitio: www.stickersgallito.pe",
  "Coordinador de Marketing", "Grupo XXX", "Lima, Perú", "Feb. 2018 - Nov. 2018", "Encargado de los esfuerzos de Marketing Digital. Responsable de la inversión y distribución de del presupuesto anual para las campañas de marketing digital. En esta empresa manejaba todos los canales de comunicación digital para su Ecommerce. Aplicamos nuevas estrategias que llevaron a incrementar las ventas, la cuota de mercado y, en general, sus ganancias.",
  "SoftLabs Perú", "Programador Backend", "Lima, Perú", "Jul. 2017 - Ene. 2018", "Desarrollo Backend en el lenguaje de programación Python. Validación de formularios.",
  "TAAG Lead", "LA Group", "Lima, Perú", "Oct. 2015 - Jun. 2017", "Jefe del área TAAG (Technology and Activation Group). Encargado de la implementación y seguimiento de las campañas digitales de clientes internacionales (Visa, CocaCola, Samsung, Falabella.",
  "Analista Digital", "YYYY", "Lima, Perú", "Oct. 2014 - Mar. 2015", "Elaboración de Dashboards con Tableau. Validación de data en Google Analytics.",
  "Analista Digital", "UNO - Agencia Digital", "Lima, Perú", "Jun. 2012 - Set. 2014", " Desarrollo de estrategias de Marketing Digital y planes tácticos para proyectos de SEO, eCommerce y Analítica Digital."
) %>% 
  detailed_entries(role, dates, company, loc, details)
```


\newpage

<!-- # Relevant Skills -->
<!-- ```{r} -->
<!-- cvskill("Data Analysis", c("Visualisation", "Data Cleaning", "Forecasting", "Modelling", "Communication", "Inference", "Machine Learning", "Web Scraping")) -->
<!-- cvskill("Programming", c("R", "Python", "SQL", "Java", "C", "C++", "HTML/CSS", "TeX", "MATLAB")) -->
<!-- ``` -->
````

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @RalfStubner added the code to produce the PDF. Also I've tried setting geometry in YAML without success.

Comment: @OmarGonzales Could you show us your YAML?

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera updated to show YAML correctly.

Comment: @OmarGonzales What happens if you replace the `name` section to `name: "\vspace{10truemm} Manuel A Gomez Ruiz"`? Does this add 10 mm space over your name?

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera got: `! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.60 \name{^^K
              space\{10truemm\} Manuel A Gomez Ruiz}{} `

Comment: @OmarGonzales Sorry for the inconvenience, I add a revised answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57842791/10215301).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name: "\\vspace{10truemm} YOUR NAME"` does the trick. Add some space you want before your name by `\vspace{}` command of LaTeX, but be sure to type two backslashes in the YAML section of `.Rmd` file.

````
---
#name: Manuel A Gomez Ruiz
name: "\\vspace{10truemm} Manuel A Gomez Ruiz"
position: "Marketing Digital - Ecommerce"
address: "Universidad de Pennsilvania"
phone: 96-330-5265
www: omardiaz.rd.io
email: "oms@gmail.com"
twitter: o_gles
github: OmonD
linkedin: orgles
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %Y')`"
aboutme: "Postgrado en Marketing Digital por la Universidad de Pennsilvania"
headcolor: 224190
geometry: "top=4cm,bottom=1cm"
output: vitae::awesomecv
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
library(vitae)
library(tibble)
library(tidyverse)
library(RefManageR)
```

# Sobre mi

 * Estudié Marketing Digital, con conocimientos de programación.
 * Programo en los lenguajes: R y Python.
 * Deporte favorito: Paleta Frontón.
 * Idiomas: Inglés, Alemán.
 * Me gusta viajar y conocer gente nueva.


# Educación
```{r}
tribble(
  ~ degree, ~ uni, ~ loc, ~ dates, ~ details,

    "Marketing, Especialización Online", "Universidad de Pennsylvania", "coursera.org", "2014", "Marketing Strategy and Brand Positioning. Customer Decision Making and the Role of Brand.",
  "Diplomado en Marketing Digital", "Universidad de Piura", "Piura, Perú", "Mar. 2013 - Jul. 2013", "Mejor trabajo final, Plan de Marketing Digital 2013.",
  "Egresado de la Facultad de Comunicación", "Universidad de Piura", "Piura, Perú", "Mar. 2007 - Dic. 2011", "Tercio Superior, Especialización en Marketing."
) %>% 
detailed_entries(degree, dates, uni, loc, details)
```

# Experiencia
```{r}
tribble(
  ~ role, ~ company, ~ loc, ~ dates, ~ details,
 "Jefe de Tecnología", "My Company", "Lima, Perú", "Ago. 2018 - Presente", 
 "Cofundador, encargado del desarrollo de la webapp y puesta en producción. Responsable del correcto funcionamiento del sitio: www.stickersgallito.pe",
 "Coordinador de Marketing", "Grupo XXX", "Lima, Perú", "Feb. 2018 - Nov. 2018", 
 "Encargado de los esfuerzos de Marketing Digital. Responsable de la inversión y distribución de del presupuesto anual para las campañas de marketing digital. En esta empresa manejaba todos los canales de comunicación digital para su Ecommerce. Aplicamos nuevas estrategias que llevaron a incrementar las ventas, la cuota de mercado y, en general, sus ganancias.",
  "SoftLabs Perú", "Programador Backend", "Lima, Perú", "Jul. 2017 - Ene. 2018", 
  "Desarrollo Backend en el lenguaje de programación Python. Validación de formularios.",
  "TAAG Lead", "LA Group", "Lima, Perú", "Oct. 2015 - Jun. 2017", "Jefe del área TAAG (Technology and Activation Group). Encargado de la implementación y seguimiento de las campañas digitales de clientes internacionales (Visa, CocaCola, Samsung, Falabella.",
  "Analista Digital", "YYYY", "Lima, Perú", "Oct. 2014 - Mar. 2015", "Elaboración de Dashboards con Tableau. Validación de data en Google Analytics.",
  "Analista Digital", "UNO - Agencia Digital", "Lima, Perú", "Jun. 2012 - Set. 2014", " Desarrollo de estrategias de Marketing Digital y planes tácticos para proyectos de SEO, eCommerce y Analítica Digital."
) %>% 
  detailed_entries(role, dates, company, loc, details)
```
````